# JSONSerializer.toJSON ClassNotFoundException in BaseDexClassLoader

Tags: java, json, classnotfoundexception, jsonserializer

I have problems with the JSONSerializer.
I have this method:

```
public List<BusinessObject> transferToDomain(String pJSON) {
        List<BusinessObject> lAllBusinessObject = new ArrayList<BusinessObject>();
        if (null == pJSON || pJSON.equals("")) {
            return lAllBusinessObject;
        }
        JSON lJSON = JSONSerializer.toJSON(pJSON);
        if (lJSON.isEmpty()) {
            return lAllBusinessObject;
        } else {
            if (lJSON.isArray()) {
                JSONArray lJSONArray = (JSONArray) lJSON;
                for (Object lObject : lJSONArray) {
                    JSONObject lJSONObject = (JSONObject) lObject;
                    lAllBusinessObject.add(doTransfer(lJSONObject));
                }
            } else {
                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) lJSON;
                BusinessObject lBusinessObject = doTransfer(json);
                if (null != lBusinessObject) {
                    lAllBusinessObject.add(lBusinessObject);
                }
            }
        }
        return lAllBusinessObject;
    }
```

It converts a JSON-String into the regarding Business object.
the line `JSONSerializer.toJSON(pJSon);` runs pretty fine for example with that Json-Code:

```
[{"user":{"uid":51,"ustempel":0,"uname":"Stefan47"
    ,"model":"USER"},"points":882,"level":27,"scomment":"Wuhuuuu"
    ,"sid":51,"rank":1,"sstempel":0,"model":"SCORE"},
{"user":{"uid":65,"ustempel":0,"uname":"Stefan61"
    ,"model":"USER"},"points":882,"level":27,"scomment":"Wuhuuuu"
    ,"sid":65,"rank":2,"sstempel":0,"model":"SCORE"},
{"user":{"uid":66,"ustempel":0,"uname":"Stefan62"
    ,"model":"USER"},"points":882,"level":27,"scomment":"Wuhuuuu"
    ,"sid":66,"rank":3,"sstempel":0,"model":"SCORE"},
{"user":{"uid":67,"ustempel":0,"uname":"Stefan63"
    ,"model":"USER"},"points":882,"level":27,"scomment":"Wuhuuuu"
    ,"sid":67,"rank":4,"sstempel":0,"model":"SCORE"},
{"user":{"uid":68,"ustempel":0,"uname":"Stefan64"
    ,"model":"USER"},"points":882,"level":27,"scomment":"Wuhuuuu"
    ,"sid":68,"rank":5,"sstempel":0,"model":"SCORE"},
{"user":{"uid":69,"ustempel":0,"uname":"Stefan65"
    ,"model":"USER"},"points":882,"level":27,"scomment":"Wuhuuuu"
    ,"sid":69,"rank":6,"sstempel":0,"model":"SCORE"},
{"user":{"uid":70,"ustempel":0,"uname":"Stefan66"
    ,"model":"USER"},"points":882,"level":27,"scomment":"Wuhuuuu"
    ,"sid":70,"rank":7,"sstempel":0,"model":"SCORE"},
{"user":{"uid":71,"ustempel":0,"uname":"Stefan67"
    ,"model":"USER"},"points":882,"level":27,"scomment":"Wuhuuuu"
    ,"sid":71,"rank":8,"sstempel":0,"model":"SCORE"},
{"user":{"uid":72,"ustempel":0,"uname":"Stefan68"
    ,"model":"USER"},"points":882,"level":27,"scomment":"Wuhuuuu"
    ,"sid":72,"rank":9,"sstempel":0,"model":"SCORE"},
{"user":{"uid":73,"ustempel":0,"uname":"Stefan69"
    ,"model":"USER"},"points":882,"level":27,"scomment":"Wuhuuuu"
    ,"sid":73,"rank":10,"sstempel":0,"model":"SCORE"}]
```

but with that JSON-Code:

```
[{"question":"Wer bist Du?"
    ,"answer1":"Jens"
    ,"answer2":"Anja"
    ,"answer3":"Stefan"
    ,"answer4":"Willi"
    ,"correctAnswer":3,"difficulty":1,"active":true,"deleted":false,"language":"DE"
    ,"key":"DE_QZ"
    ,"cat":"Die Bundesliga"
    ,"qid":1303,"qstempel":1390138057765,"model":"QUESTION"},
{"question":"Wer bist Du?"
    ,"answer1":"Jens"
    ,"answer2":"Anja"
    ,"answer3":"Stefan"
    ,"answer4":"Willi"
    ,"correctAnswer":3,"difficulty":1,"active":true,"deleted":false,"language":"DE"
    ,"key":"DE_QZ"
    ,"cat":"Premiure League"
    ,"qid":1636,"qstempel":1390138059690,"model":"QUESTION"},
{"question":"Wer bist Du?"
    ,"answer1":"Jens"
    ,"answer2":"Anja"
    ,"answer3":"Stefan"
    ,"answer4":"Willi"
    ,"correctAnswer":3,"difficulty":3,"active":true,"deleted":false,"language":"DE"
    ,"key":"DE_QZ"
    ,"cat":"WM"
    ,"qid":1582,"qstempel":1390138059395,"model":"QUESTION"},
{"question":"Wer bist Du?"
    ,"answer1":"Jens"
    ,"answer2":"Anja"
    ,"answer3":"Stefan"
    ,"answer4":"Willi"
    ,"correctAnswer":3,"difficulty":3,"active":true,"deleted":false,"language":"DE"
    ,"key":"DE_QZ"
    ,"cat":"Die Bundesliga"
    ,"qid":1421,"qstempel":1390138058497,"model":"QUESTION"},
{"question":"Wer bist Du?"
    ,"answer1":"Jens"
    ,"answer2":"Anja"
    ,"answer3":"Stefan"
    ,"answer4":"Willi"
    ,"correctAnswer":3,"difficulty":3,"active":true,"deleted":false,"language":"DE"
    ,"key":"DE_QZ"
    ,"cat":"Premiure League"
    ,"qid":1708,"qstempel":1390138060083,"model":"QUESTION"},
{"question":"Wer bist Du?"
    ,"answer1":"Jens"
    ,"answer2":"Anja"
    ,"answer3":"Stefan"
    ,"answer4":"Willi"
    ,"correctAnswer":3,"difficulty":1,"active":true,"deleted":false,"language":"DE"
    ,"key":"DE_QZ"
    ,"cat":"WM"
    ,"qid":1470,"qstempel":1390138058774,"model":"QUESTION"},
{"question":"Wer bist Du?"
    ,"answer1":"Jens"
    ,"answer2":"Anja"
    ,"answer3":"Stefan"
    ,"answer4":"Willi"
    ,"correctAnswer":3,"difficulty":2,"active":true,"deleted":false,"language":"DE"
    ,"key":"DE_QZ"
    ,"cat":"Premiure League"
    ,"qid":1667,"qstempel":1390138059857,"model":"QUESTION"},
{"question":"Wer bist Du?"
    ,"answer1":"Jens"
    ,"answer2":"Anja"
    ,"answer3":"Stefan"
    ,"answer4":"Willi"
    ,"correctAnswer":3,"difficulty":2,"active":true,"deleted":false,"language":"DE"
    ,"key":"DE_QZ"
    ,"cat":"WM"
    ,"qid":1539,"qstempel":1390138059158,"model":"QUESTION"},
{"question":"Wer bist Du?"
    ,"answer1":"Jens"
    ,"answer2":"Anja"
    ,"answer3":"Stefan"
    ,"answer4":"Willi"
    ,"correctAnswer":3,"difficulty":2,"active":true,"deleted":false,"language":"DE"
    ,"key":"DE_QZ"
    ,"cat":"Die Bundesliga"
    ,"qid":1381,"qstempel":1390138058267,"model":"QUESTION"}]
```

this exception is thrown and I have absolutly no idear why???

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.beans.PropertyDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/bc.qz.client.android-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/bc.qz.client.android-2, /system/lib]]

Could anyone give me some advice why that happens?

Thanks in advance

Stefan

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.beans.PropertyDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/bc.qz.client.android-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/bc.qz.client.android-2, /system/lib]]

Something has a dependency that is not loaded in one code path but is on another. The Android API only provides a subset of the Java 6 API:

- [java.beans package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/package-summary.html) in Java 6
- [java.beans package](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/beans/package-summary.html) in Android

`PropertyDescriptor` is not provided. If your own code does not use this type then it is likely one of your libraries requires it.

Comment: it is very strange... I put the creation of that class into another activity(onCreate) of my android project and now it works without any exception. +1 for your help